# ESD_Null while create SendEmailDefinition SOAP API

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api

When I try to create an SendEmailDefiniton with Soap API I've received an error code:
42116
I found that this error code means: ESD_Null Value
in: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/42000_42999_emailsenddefinition_object.html
But it's not self explanatory.
Who can suggest what's incorrect in my SOAP Envelope?

```
  <soap:Body>
<CreateRequest xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI" xmlns:ns2="urn:fault.partner.exacttarget.com">
  <Objects xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="EmailSendDefinition">
    <CustomerKey>OZKey2</CustomerKey>
    <Name>OZ Test Send definition</Name>
    <Description>OZ Test Send definition</Description>
    <SendClassification>
      <Client><!--Strange because I didn't set it intentionally-->
        <ID>11111</ID><!--Value is replaced-->
      </Client>
      <PartnerKey></PartnerKey>
      <ObjectID>5765a93d-4b00-ee11-a5ba-5cba2c196e68</ObjectID>
      <CustomerKey>Default Commercial</CustomerKey>
      <Name>Default Commercial</Name>
      <Description>Default Commercial Send Classification</Description>
      <SenderProfile>
        <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
        <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>
        <CustomerKey>Default</CustomerKey>
      </SenderProfile>
    </SendClassification>
    <SendDefinitionList>
      <CustomObjectID>8f4f7ddc-4c00-ee11-a5ba-5cba2c196e68</CustomObjectID>
      <DataSourceTypeID>CustomObject</DataSourceTypeID>
    </SendDefinitionList>
    <Email>
      <PartnerKey></PartnerKey>
      <CreatedDate>2023-10-13T08:03:07.36</CreatedDate>
      <ID>3244</ID>
      <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>
      <CustomerKey>0CF02E06-CE29-4B56-B8B2-B0F9744AFF0A</CustomerKey>
      <Name>Text only in API</Name>
      <Subject>Example subject</Subject>
      <Status>New</Status>
    </Email>
    <TestEmailAddr>someemail@outlook.com</TestEmailAddr>
    <EmailSubject>OZ Test Send Definition Email Subject</EmailSubject>
  </Objects>
</CreateRequest>
</soap:Body>
```

The authentication is okay, because I can create an email, and retrieve it, I also retrieve the EmailClassification for the EmailSendDefinition.

Comment: Do the comments in the answer to [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/316109/creating-an-emailsenddefinition-with-wsproxy) help to solve this?

Comment: Yes, you are right, it did help. The issue was with not validated Send Classification. Thank you!

Comment: In that case, answer your own question - you can! Add some detail please. This will be helpful for people who face the same issue later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root cause was in a not verified email address in the default "Sender Profile" that was selected in "Send Classification". You can find the message about the not verified email in the top of "Send Classification" menu when you select the particular "Send Classification".

I created a new "Sender Profile". You can find it in Email Studio in the "Admin" menu under "Send management". In a new "Sender Profile" I entered an email and clicked on the button "Verify", then opened the link that was sent to my email. It was a bit strange because it said that the link was expired even so and I clicked it almost instantly. But it was enough to verify an email.
Then in "Send Classification" menu I choose a newly created "Sender profile" with verified email.

And after that, I was able to create a new ESD entry with SOAP API.
The error message is not clear at all.